# Как создать тест для ui->plainTextEdit?

Tags: юнит-тесты, qt

Есть проект с двумя виджетами `QPlainTextEdit`:

```
//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_plainTextEdit_textChanged();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

//mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_plainTextEdit_textChanged()
{
    ui->plainTextEdit_2->setPlainText(ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText());
}
}
```

Как видно отсюда: при вводе текст в `plainTextEdit`, содержимое автоматически переноситься в `plainTextEdit2`.

И теперь я пытаюсь написать тест для этой простенькой программы. Но не знаю как добраться до виджета `plainTextEdit`, ведь он находиться в "дебрях" `ui->plainTextEdit` и указатель `ui` к тому же `private`.

Вот тестовый класс который я подготовил:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QtTest>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class Test_MainWindow :  public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Test_MainWindow();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void plainText(); //мой тестовый метод
    void testCase1();
};

void Test_MainWindow::plainText() {
    //???      
    QTest::keyClicks(ui->plainTextEdit, "Text");
    QCOMPARE(ui->plainTextEdit_2->toPlainText(), QString("Text"));

}

Test_MainWindow::Test_MainWindow()
{
}

void Test_MainWindow::testCase1()
{
    QVERIFY2(true, "Failure");
}

QTEST_MAIN(Test_MainWindow)

#include "tst_mainwindow.moc"
```

Здесь шаблон, который помогает сделать сам `Qt Creator` и немного моих набросок.

Я также пытался полностью унаследоваться от класса `MainWindow`, но компилятор почему то выдал мне кучу ошибок и сразу пришлось отказаться от этой затеи.

Какие будут предложения по этому поводу?

Comment: зачем добираться до автосгенерированного объекта виджета? И вообще вы можете провести тестирвоание с помощью одного из инструментов тестирования , например TestComplete trial(умеет работать с qt)

Comment: Считайте, что сгенерирвоанные объекты виджетов - черные ящики. Вызывайте их с начальными значениями , а дальше проверяйте, что оно установилось.

Comment: Моей конечной целью является проверка (целостность) функции `void on_plainTextEdit_textChanged()`. Я в принципе тестирую именно ее, а не виджет. Но он (on_plainTextEdit_textChanged) не принимает на вход данные. По этому я и уцепился за `plainTextEdit`.